# ArcPy specific fields to CSV print() issue

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, csv

I have made this code that extracts specific fields of feature layers into a CSV file.
Code works fine. I have an issue the way it writes to CSV. Output is as below:

```
(211793  '10290-03')
```

I actually want it to look like this

```
211793   10290-03
```

I don't want () or '.
Code is as below:

```
import arcpy
import fileinput    
proj = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')      
#m = proj.listMaps()[0]       
m = proj.activeMap  
ml = m.listLayers("Data")                           # First Group Layer
for gl in ml:
if gl.isGroupLayer:                             # Check if its Group Layer     
    arcpy.AddMessage("-"+gl.name+"-")
    mml = gl.listLayers()
    for sgl in mml:
        if sgl.isGroupLayer:                    # Check if its Sub Group Layer
            arcpy.AddMessage("--"+sgl.name+"--")
            lyrs = sgl.listLayers()
            for lyr in lyrs:
                arcpy.AddMessage(lyr.name)
                with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,['Assetic_ID','FL_ID']) as cur:   
                    for rows in cur:
                        for row in rows:
                            with open("C:\\test\\file.csv", 'a') as f:
                                print ((rows), file =f)
arcpy.AddMessage("Finished")
```

Comment: Nothing to do with ArcPy. This is all on your `print` statement. CSV is actually a specific format, and you need to check for commas in strings to quote them, and control characters to escape, or you might have trouble down the line.

Comment: Try for ThisRow in rows: f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(ThisRow[0],ThisRow[1])) but still heed the warning by Vince, there could be a comma, unicode or escape char in your table that will cause problems in your output. Excel uses quoted strings to avoid some of the problems which would change your format statement to '{0},"{1}"\n'.format(ThisRow[0],ThisRow[1]) just to be sure coincidental commas are interpreted as parts of strings rather than the start of a new column.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing:

```
 print ((rows), file =f)
```

with:

```
f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(rows[0],rows[1]))
```

works.